# How to always trigger function of <select> tag

Tags: javascript, selection, default, dropdown

I wrote a select tag (have default selected) and take the option value to trigger another js function:

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById("sel");

function somefunction() {
  console.log(selectElement.value);
};
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange='somefunction()'>
    <option selected="selected" value='yes'>Yes</option>
    <option value='no'>No</option>
    <option value='all'>All</option>
 </select>
```

However, if I keep the `onchange` event, it only triggers the function when I change the selection. I also want to trigger the function when page is loaded with the default selection that i have set (which is Yes in the above example).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onload function to your body tag:

```
<body onLoad='somefunction()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to build an independent function for calculating the selected index. Then I would manually map a variable to the `<select>` element,  and attach an `onchange()` handler than calls this function, passing itself in as a parameter.

With this setup, you have both a function to calculate the selected value of any `<select>` element, and the target `<select>` element already mapped to a variable for easy access. You can then simply pass that variable into the function on page load:

```js
/* Function to grab the selection, which takes a `<select>` element as a parameter */
function getSelectedIndexes(select) {
  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
select.onchange = function(e) {
  console.log(getSelectedIndexes(this)); // Selection on change
}

console.log(getSelectedIndexes(select)); // Default selection
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected> Select
  </option>
  <option selected="selected" value='yes'> Yes
  </option>
  <option value='no'> No
  </option>
  <option value='all'> All
  </option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the function when the window is loaded? I guess that will solve 
your problem.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (selectEl.value) // or use (selectEl.value == "yes)
    somefunction()
};

var selectEl = document.getElementById("sel");

function somefunction() {
  console.log(selectEl.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange='somefunction()'>
    
 <option selected="selected" value='yes'>Yes</option>
  <option value='no'>No</option>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
    </select>
```